# How do I fix linting errors without committing the fixed changes?

Tags: git, eslint, husky

My current setup utilizes [husky](https://www.npmjs.com/package/husky) and [lint-staged](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lint-staged) to check commits for linting errors (ESLint). This is what I have in my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue,html,json}": [
      "./node_modules/.bin/eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
}
```

What I want is to check for lint errors, fix them, but keep the changeset staged so developers can review the changes. The problem is that using the `--fix` flag fixes linting issues and quietly commits everything. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Not having used eslint, I can't answer the eslint/husky question itself. But consider letting the commits happen. Commits are good! They keep stuff separate! If you want it combined later, use `git rebase -i` and squash the parts you want combined (or use the `git reset --soft` and re-commit trick, or any of the other variants that all achieve the desired result).